# What does "terminating incoming connections" mean and what does it imply for network security?

Tags: networking, security

During a recent conversation with a network security team, one of them said: "Look, if that server is terminating incoming connections, it must be in the DMZ."

What does it mean to "terminate" network connectivity in this context?

Comment: You'll need to give us more context. "Terminate" can mean "filter" or (more likely here) it can mean "provide an endpoint" (for a socket or tunnel).

Comment: You’re right. The context was guessed by @Jesse P. below.

Comment: If any of the answers below were helpful, please mark them as the accepted answer. Alternatively, you can post your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a hop on the path that a client (user) accesses publicly, whether a final destination (such as a webserver), or just a proxy/firewall, etc. that leads to another hop, it needs to sit in the DMZ and not be inside of your internal network.  This way, no holes need to be punched for direct user access into your internal network, and only holes between the DMZ host and its backend (like a database server) need to exist.

So, in this context, "terminate" simply means whatever the user directly accesses publicly.

Answer (score 2):

"Terminate" has two major meanings:

It can mean filter or break a connection, or (much more likely here) it can mean "provide an endpoint" (accept a socket connection or create a tunnel end).

Answer (score 0):

Destination server might be reseting or terminating session so that session is closed and unable to access resources on servers from outside networks
When services on specific ports are not in listening mode session will get reseted or terminated at destination server end .

To overcome this issue . please ensure services on specific ports are in listening mode in destination server which in depolyed in DMZ segment..